# get $_FILES['image'] in Jquery then send it as parameter to another function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form where I must choose a file, then I want to get the $_FILES['image'] array to be able to pass it as an argument to a Jquery function. How can I do it ?
Thank you

Comment: `$_FILES['image']` is php, and is only available to php, after uploading a file. Therefore, i'm going to go with this is not possible. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Kevin B, I have a modal form "modal.html" where I select the image, then I have a php script "storeimage.php" used to process the image and store it, then I want to store the image once I submit the modal form, the Jquery script I'm using for that is on the main page : "main.html". thank you

Answer (score 0):

The array `$_FILES['image']` is only available from PHP on the server. If you have to go via the server you'll need a script to return the array to your javascript.

However, if you don't need to go via a server you can obtain the list of files directly from the DOM in Javascript.

Assuming your HTML contains a `<form>` with this:

```
<input id="fileItem" type="file">
```

Then you can get the selected files like this:

```
var myFileList = document.getElementById('fileItem').files;
```

You can get more details on the FileList object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), and details on the File object are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Answer (score 0):

you can also just get the array from the php file (assuming its included in your html page) and assign it to a javascript variable like

> $x = < ?php $_FILES['images'] ?>